# Bayesian Probability

Tags: probability, bayesian-networks

> I have probability P(A|B=T,C=F,D=F,G=T) is this same as computing
>   P(A|B=T)*P(A|C=F)*P(A|D=F) *P(A|G=T)  ?
>   P(A|B=T,C=F,D=F,G=T)=P(A|B=T)*P(A|C=F)*P(A|D=F) *P(A|G=T) ? where A is
>   the child of B, C, D, G thanks!

Comment: As stated the question is not specifically related to programming, but it might be appropriate for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it **is not** true that the following holds.

```
P(A|B,C) = P(A|B) • P(A|C)
```

The following **is** true, however. ([Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem))

```
           P(B,C|A) • P(A)
P(A|B,C) = ━━━━━━━━
                P(B,C)
```

Furthermore, if B and C are conditionally independent given A, the following **is** true.

```
P(A|B,C) ∝ P(B|A) • P(C|A) • P(A)
```

Comment: I'm being a bit pedantic here, but the term for `P(B,C|A) = P(B|A)*P(C|A)` is *conditional independence*, which is not the same thing as independence. It is possible for random variables to be conditionally independent but not independent, and vice versa, so the last equation can't be assumed from independence. You can read more [at this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22407/independence-and-conditional-independence-between-random-variables)

Comment: @eigenchris Absolutely. I'm aware of both kinds of independence, but in my haste I said the wrong thing. Thanks for catching it.